# html file that doesn't work properly using html service

Tags: google-apps-script

I've repeated exactly all the steps described in Google Html Service [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#CreatingHTML), with the only one difference that this is my html file:

```
<html>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
</html>
```

but when I open the url of my deployed script the page displays only the string "google" and does not recognize the link. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

You are missing head and body parts, try to add them, although it is said that they are just optional and see if it works..

Answer (score 0):

That should work. If you post the entirety of your script here I can try it myself and see what happens.